Jpg image cannot be opened
I have an image taken from a Canon digital camera. When transferring the JPG images to the PC, none of them work, they cannot be opened.
Could you check if you have any fix options? I used several programs but no luck.
The memory card was new, and it was not formatted before starting to take photos
https://drive.google.com/file/d/15WFXGQ-jIqq8yNzebnXMkk3Rac3Gme1x/view?usp=sharing
Thanks!!

How do you transfer them to the PC?

Hi there. You've returned to this question with further information (below), but you have not yet addressed this critical question - how are you getting the images off the memory card and into your computer?

I’m voting to close this question because It is not viable having a question that require us to go into someone's else Google Drive. It can be potentially dangerous.

@Rafael Any file you download is potentially dangerous, but then if you can't show photos this seriously reduces the site's usability.

It was I who cast the decisive vote that closed this question, but not because of any data security concerns; my reason is that the question needs additional details/clarity. If the OP can provide this clarity, then the question can be reopened.

Below OP says "The memory card was new, and it was not formatted before starting to take photos". Even if a card was bought formatted, you should still format it in-camera.

@WeatherVane The filesystem type of the SD card is mandated by the SD card standard so they come pre-formatted with a filesystem the camera can use. And if the card were not formatted the camera would complain quite loudly on the first photo, while the OP mentions several shots taken?

Looking at your sample with a hex browser, the  beginning of the file contains 192K or random data. In particular I cannot find what looks like a proper Jpeg file header.
The beginning of your file:

The beginning of a JPEG from my Canon camera, showing proper FFD8 Jpeg marker and recognizable Exif data (camera model, time):

After the 192K or random data, the file contents are 1.3MB of null bytes.
The size of the file itself (1.6MB) is much smaller than the usual out of camera JPEG if you choose the high quality JPEG (4MB on my very old 12Mpix camera, 7MB on my not-so-recent 20Mpix camera) and this alone should make you suspicious. In addition if you try to compress the file (make a ZIP from it), it compresses very well (down to 300K) when real JPEG are nearly uncompressible.
So, in short, your file is totally corrupted and there is nothing you can get out of it.
Why it is so is another question, if you cannot see the pictures in the camera playback or if you transferred the file to your PC using a card reader this is probably a SD card malfunction, with not much hop to recover anything. If the images can still be seen in the camera playback then it could be a transfer problem but you will have to tell us exactly how you did the transfer (USB cable? Wifi? Card reader?).

Hello!
Well, thank you very much for the response and analysis.
Yesterday I tried to take them to the digital camera.
I connected the SD to my PC to transfer the broken images. Then I put that SD in the camera, and the image thumbnail was not displayed either, an error appears.
It's a shame, thanks for the help!
